# How to upload image automatically if user wants to edit info PHP MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a registration form which takes inputs username, email, password, and image. If user wants to edit his profile, I add all values in inputs and user can submit form again. But when he click on update button the image should be uploaded automatically and not empty. On my end it is empty. You can see in the image that user want to update Info but can't see the uploaded image. Other info was retrieved.

my front end screenshot:

[image: my front end screenshot]

I tried to show the image using src attribute but this isn't going to work. Please let me know how I can achieve this.

Comment: please add the relevant code parts to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file input can only select from the local filesystem, so you can't pre-populate it with something from the server.

Use an `<img` tag to display existing images from the server.

For example, in your HTML form:

```
File:-
    <input type="file" name="image"><br><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="old_image" value="<?php echo $row['images'] ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo "files/images/".$row['images']; ?>">
```

Comment: Can you please show me the code to get image from server using id?

Comment: I don't know anything about how or where you store the images, or the file names, or how you associate the images with an ID - is that an ID in your database? You gave no code or context about your system, so it's difficult to suggest anything specific. Please edit your question with more details, if you need more help.